# How to add dynamical images into datatable in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to get a summary of a dataframe. In my MWE it is about whether the data is bigger or smaller than 5. For that I want to have a table (ideally a DT::datatable, so you can search for parameter names and sort...). In the first column you see the name, in the second the percentage of values smaller than five and in the third column there is a picture that helps you visualizing where these small values are.

Here you get an idea how it could look like:

[image: Image how I want the table to look like]

It was generated using this code:

```
library(shiny)

df <- iris[,1:4]

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("table_replacement")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table_replacement <- renderUI(
    lapply(names(df), function(param){
      fluidRow(
        column(2, param),
        column(2, paste0(round(sum(df[[param]]<5)/nrow(df)*100,2), "%")),
        column(8, imageOutput(
          outputId = paste0("is_it_big", param),
          height = "50px"
        ))
      )
    })
  )
  lapply(names(df), function(param){
    output[[paste0("is_it_big", param)]] <- renderImage({
      pngdata <- array(0, dim = c(10, nrow(df), 3))
      pngdata[,df[[param]]<5,1] <- 1
      outfile <- tempfile(fileext = "png")
      png::writePNG(pngdata, outfile)
      list(
        src = outfile,
        contentType = "image/png",
        width = 200,
        height = 20,
        alt = paste("png for", param)
      )
    }, deleteFile = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Without the datatable-context I get it to work, however if I include the pictures in a datatable, then the renderImage seems not to be activated.

Please feel free also to propose improvements on how I create the png. E.g. I would like to know whether it is really necessary to create a temporary file.

[image: Images are not loaded if constructed inside a datatable]

Here is the code to reproduce the second image:

```
library(shiny)

df <- iris[, 1:4]

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("dtout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dtout <- DT::renderDT({
    perc <- sapply(names(df), function(param) {
      paste0(round(sum(df[[param]] < 5) / nrow(df) * 100, 2), "%")
    })
    images <- sapply(names(df), function(param) {
      as.character(imageOutput(
        outputId = paste0("is_it_big", param),
        height = "50px"
      ))
    })
    dt <- data.frame(
      params = names(df),
      percentages = perc,
      images = images
    )
    DT::datatable(
      dt,
      escape = FALSE
    )
  })
  lapply(names(df), function(param) {
    output[[paste0("is_it_big", param)]] <- renderImage(
      {
        print(paste("Rendering", param))
        pngdata <- array(0, dim = c(10, nrow(df), 3))
        pngdata[, df[[param]] < 5, 1] <- 1
        outfile <- tempfile(fileext = "png")
        png::writePNG(pngdata, outfile)
        list(
          src = outfile,
          contentType = "image/png",
          width = 200,
          height = 20,
          alt = paste("png for", param)
        )
      },
      deleteFile = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can say that the images were not even rendered, because the print statement was not executed. I have once read something like there is binding and unbinding to tell shiny that new elements have been created on the fly using javascript/plain html, but I was not able to understand that. I am just mentioning that because it might help someone with a bit more knowledge (it might also be not helpful, I do not know).

And one more thing would be great: I would like the images to be loaded lazily, that means only if shown to the user. This would be great because the datatable only shows 10 out of my ~200 parameters with ~20000 rows, and it is taking very long to compute these pictures for some reason. But I will try to optimize this later, even without lazy-loading it would be great to get this to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the temporary png files to base64 in order to avoid dealing with files.

The `renderDT` function has argument `server=TRUE` by default, which means only the visible part of the table is loaded in the html page. This is "lazy" as you say.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(png) # to use writePNG
library(base64enc) # to use dataURI

makeImage <- function(df, param) {
  pngdata <- array(0, dim = c(10L, nrow(df), 3L))
  pngdata[, df[[param]] < 5, 1L] <- 1
  outfile <- tempfile(fileext = "png")
  writePNG(pngdata, outfile)
  dataURI(file = outfile, mime = "image/png")
}

makeDataWithImages <- function(df) {
  perc <- sapply(names(df), function(param) {
    paste0(round(sum(df[[param]] < 5) / nrow(df) * 100, 2), "%")
  })
  images <- sapply(names(df), function(param) {
    as.character(tags$img(
      src = makeImage(df, param),
      height = "50px"
    ))
  })
  data.frame(
    params      = names(df),
    percentages = perc,
    images      = images
  )
}

# shiny app
df <- iris[, 1:4]
dat <- makeDataWithImages(df)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dtout")
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {
  output[["dtout"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]